# Unable to update chardet using pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm a newbie Python programmer trying to import folium
When I do so, I get dependency error, so I'm trying to update one of the libraries (charset) via pip.
Below you can see that I run the pip update command and it claims to have updated charset.
Run it again, and it updates again. Weird.
Look for outdated libraries and it still shows the old version.

I think there is a clue in "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable" but I don't know where to go from here, please help.

See below:

```
(xenial)barry@localhost:~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests$ pip install **chardet** --upgrade<br />
**__Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable__**<br />
Collecting chardet<br />
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)<br />
Installing collected packages: chardet<br />
**Successfully installed chardet-3.0.4<br />**
**(xenial)barry@localhost:~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests$ pip install chardet --upgrade<br />**
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable<br />
Collecting chardet<br />
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)<br />
Installing collected packages: chardet<br />
**Successfully installed chardet-3.0.4<br />**
(xenial)barry@localhost:~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests$ pip list --outdated<br />
Package       Version Latest Type <br />
------------- ------- ------ -----<br />
**chardet       2.3.0   3.0.4  wheel<br />**
pygobject     3.20.0  3.34.0 sdist<br />
python-debian 0.1.27  0.1.36 wheel<br />
setuptools    20.7.0  45.1.0 wheel<br />
six           1.10.0  1.14.0 wheel<br />
wheel         0.29.0  0.34.2 wheel<br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pip you are running is installed systemwide, but the package you are installing is installed into `~/.local/`. You can try running `~/.local/bin/pip` or `~/.local/bin/python` to get the pip/python you are installing to.

A good and common practice is to set up "virtual environments" with a tool known as virtualenv. With that tool you can keep different python environments set up at the same time, and install different versions of packages for different projects that may require the same package but different or even incompatible versions.

Comment: I have run the commands prefixed as you suggsteded, and have the same result (it says it is updated, but had not recognised that it has updated) <br>(xenial)barry@localhost:~/Desktop$ ~/.local/bin/pip install chardet --upgrade
(xenial)barry@localhost:~/Desktop$ ~/.local/bin/pip list --outdated

Comment: python -m pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /home/barry/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)

Comment: I gave up working out why my pip was so confused, so as suggsted followed advice on using virtualenv. Here is a good article which I was able to follow and it worked first time. Thanks for your help. https://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/